# Accessing the React dev environment, through Apache reverse proxy

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

I'm just trying to get started with the basic create-react-app. I can access the development environment fine via the typical localhost:3000, but I'd like to access this via my public apache server. I've set this up via a reverse proxy, on a subdirectory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPass /react-app http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /react-app http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works, except that references in the index.html are coded to look from the root directory only. For instance the js bundle is under:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js">
```

When its actual location is really under `/react-app/static/js/bundle.js`. Alternatively this could also be made into a relative URI.

My couple of questions:

- How can I run the react-app development environment under a non-root directory?
- Alternatively, is there a better way to access the dev environment than the this Apache reverse-proxy method?